# How to serve multiple static files using dropwizard for each url?

Tags: java, http, dropwizard, assetbundle

I used,

```
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets", "/", "a.js"));
    bootstrap.addBundle(new MultiPartBundle());
```

but I need to serve a file say b.js on entering /b and c.js on entering /c.

How to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map specific resources by specifying the resourcePath as the actual file. So, using the examples you have mentioned this is how you could achieve that:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/a.js", "/a", null, "a"));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/b.js", "/b", null, "b"));
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/c.js", "/c", null, "c"));
```

However, I think this is not a good practice and will become unmanageable over time, to keep a mapping of a URL per resource.

**UPDATE**
For a more maintainable list of mappings I would recommend using something like the [Configurable Assets Bundle for Dropwizard](https://github.com/dropwizard-bundles/dropwizard-configurable-assets-bundle), where multiple mappings can be described on the configuration file. I have created a simple DW [project](https://github.com/andremanuelbarbosa/SOQ48705518) which uses this lib and replicates the behaviour described on the question.

Comment: I tried this. But only /c is working after that. (last line of the bootstrap.addBundle() )

Comment: Could you please show me what is the correct way to serve static files on each path?

Comment: Is this a good way?

`
    @GET
    @Path("a")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public InputStream index() {
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream("/a.js");
    }
`

Comment: You are right about only the last mapping working @gkvm, I have implemented and tested them incrementally and did not test the previous endpoints. I have edited the answer with a full working solution and also proposed a solution where the mappings can be maintained in a more efficient manner.